# generate 30 lambda expression using for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, lambda

I want to create event set on mouse click for 30 objects all of them do the same:

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    seats[i].setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        seats[i].setEffect(lighting);       
    });
    }
```

But I keep getting these error:

```
error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
        seats[i].setEffect(lighting);
```

Any suggestion how to fix it instead of writing it manually 30 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference the variable `i` inside the lambda expression, as its value will have changed when the lambda is executed. Instead, do:

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    Node seat = seats[i];
    seat.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        seat.setEffect(lighting);       
    });
}
```

This assumes `lighting` is either explicitly `final` (i.e. declared as `final`), "effectively final" (i.e. is only assigned a value once, so could be declared `final` without introducing a compile error), or is a field (not a local variable).

Answer (score 0):

**A local variable must be final or *effectively final* in a lambda expression.**

What this means is that you can not make *assignments* to local-variables used in a lambda, where local means *defined in the method-scope that contains the lambda expression*.

So this does **not** work:

```
//in method
int a = 5;
x.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
   a = a + 5 // <-- assignment       
});
```

Neither does this:

```
//in method
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++) { // <-- assignment
   x.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
      x.doSomething(a); // <-- a is not effectively final  
   });
}
```

This works:

```
// in class
private int a = 5;

// in method
x.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
   a = a + 5 // <-- works since a is not a local variable   
});
```

This works as well:

```
// in method
MyObj o = new MyObj(); // object with member public int a;

x.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
   o.a = o.a + 5 // o is a local variable, but o is not reassigned, only a is.       
});
```

Comment: What do assignments have to do with it? You cannot *access* a non-final (or non-effectively final) local variable in a lambda expression. The OP doesn't even attempt to assign anything in the lambda expression in the question.

Comment: @James_D True I was unclear. I have clarified my answer.